# IOS ViewController navigation path - how to navigate back programatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, xcode-storyboard

I'm using IOS5 Storyboard. My View Controller path is as follows:

```
tabbarVC --> navigationVC-1 --> tableVC-1 --(via segue push)-> tableVC-2 --(via segue modal)-> navigationVC-2 --> tableVC-3
```

In the cancel button callback action method in tableVC-3 I call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`  that successfully gets me back to tableVC-2. However when I try to examine the navigation path backwards in the debugger, I don't see a way to access tableVC-2 from navigationVC-2. I expected navigationVC-2 to maintain a link to tableVC-2 or navigationVC-1 but it doesn't seem to. Please see my debugger output below.

Can someone explain the navigation hierarchy and how to traverse the chain backwards programatically?

```
(gdb) po self
<tableVC-3: 0x6d33340>

(gdb) po (UIViewController*) [self navigationController]
<UINavigationController: 0x6d33560>

(gdb) po (UIViewController*)[[self navigationController] navigationController]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

(gdb) po (UIViewController*)[[self navigationController] topViewController]
<tableVC-3: 0x6d33340>

(gdb) po (UIViewController*)[[self navigationController] presentingViewController]
<UITabBarController: 0x6b2eba0>

(gdb) po (UIViewController*)[[self navigationController] presentedViewController]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.

(gdb) po (UIViewController*)[[self navigationController] visibleViewController]
<tableVC-3: 0x6d33340>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but just to help anyone else who comes across this issue, there's a single command which'll make your life easier..

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

Easy when you stumble across the right command, isn't it !

So, supposing you had a series of three screens in a Navigation Controller, and on the *third* screen you wanted the "Back" button to take you back to the *initial* screen.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // change the back button and add an event handler
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(handleBack:)];
}


-(void)handleBack:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"About to go back to the first screen..");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Going throw an old response tough of updating it to be more complet.
To address this question :

> Can someone explain the navigation hierarchy and how to traverse the chain backwards programatically?

The structure of your navigation :

> tabbarVC --> navigationVC-1 --> tableVC-1 --(via segue push)-> tableVC-2 --(via segue modal)-> navigationVC-2 --> tableVC-3

Can be explain like this :
The TabbarVC is showing it's 'selectedViewController' (navigationVC-1).
NavigationVC-1 has its navigation stack compose of TableVC-1 and TableVC-2 (topViewController of NavigagtionVC-1)
Then NavigationVC-2 is presented Modally over the tabbarVC, so tabbarVC is the `presentingViewController` and NavigationVC-2 is the `presentedViewController`

So in order to reach tableVC-2 from tableVC-3 you would need to do something like this :

```
[(UINavigationController *)[(UITabBarController *)[tableVC-3 presentingViewController] selectedViewController] topViewController];
```

(don't do that in production code)

`[tableVC-3 presentingViewController]` as well as `[tableVC-3.navigationController presentingViewController]` will give you back the `UITabBarController`.

---

If you are using a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you should use it's `push` and `pop` method to put UIViewController on or off the "presentation stack".
You will be able to access the `UINavigationController` from those `UIViewController` like this:

```
self.navigationController
```

If you want to go back more than one `UIViewController` on the "presentation stack" you can use this method on the `UINavigationController`

> popToViewController:animated:
>   Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.
>       - (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

---

To dismiss a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewController) that was presented modally, the `UIViewController` that have presented it need to dismiss it with :

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

So in this case it should be :

```
[tableVC-2 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Actually my question is different. Notice that I have 2 navigation controllers in play. My question is how to get back to the first navigation controller. If you see the debug output I pasted, there doesn't seem to be any way to traverse back to the first navigation controller.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Without the 2nd nav controller, the 'modal' type segue doesn't seem to work (app crashes).

Comment: @mpprdev - Ok I get it, I'm less use to segue. You don't want to go back you want to dismiss your modal presentation.

Comment: Not linked to the question but thanks, I've been looking for the pop function for a while but hadn't found the navigation controller (was looking in parent controller... Now it all makes cense

Comment: A little remark: if you want to go back to the previous view, without passing it as parameter, you can just use the following code: [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 4):

After some research using this and a couple other questions for modal UIViewControllers in storyboard to go back two views I used

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The comment made me try `[self.navigationController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. The structure was like: Navigation Controller -> TableView -> (via push segue) -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller. This worked with me! Moreover, it gave me insight of how things work.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift

If you are using a navigation controller the you can navigate back to the previous view controller with

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or back to the root view controller with

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```